What is the difference between the superposition principle and completeness relation in quantum mechanics?
As far as I know, we say that any wavefunction which is a superposition of the solutions of the Schrödinger equation are also valid solutions.
On the other hand, according to completeness relation we say that any wavefunction can be spanned by the eigenvectors of an operator.
So if we consider the Schrödinger equation and the Hamiltonian operator, any function is a solution of the Schrödinger equation.
Where am I wrong?

This question is similar to: Combine the completeness and linearity of Schrodinger equation's solution, can we say that any wavefunction can solve any Schrodinger equation?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. --See also related and linked questions therein.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

The superposition principle can be stated in every vector space. In QT it is the mathematical statement that, if two (non-vanishing) vectors $\psi$ and $\psi'$ represent pure states, then also every (non-vanishing) complex linear combination of them $a\psi +b\psi'$ represents a state. In other words, the entities which represent pure states are members of a complex vector space.
(States are not vectors, but they are non-vanishing vectors up to non-vanishing factors)
Completeness is a more technical mathematical property of the linear space of the vectors representing states. It requires  that every Cauchy sequence of vectors converges somewhere in the space. In other words, the space is Hilbert (not ony Banach since the norm is induced by a Hermitianinner product).
It is of the utmost relevance in QT because it produces a number of crucial physical consequences. First of all, the various versions of the spectral theorem of self-adjoint operators (observables). In the simplest case: an observable which attains a discrete spectrum of values has a set of (orthogonal) eigenvectors (eigenstates) whose (topological) span is the whole Hilbert space.
In particular, every vector representing a state can be decomposed as a linear combination of these eigenvectors.
However, none of these properties implies that every function is a solution of the Schroedinger equation! I.e. every vector is an eigenstate of the Hamiltonian operstor. That is because a linear combination of two or more eigenvectors with non vanishing coefficients and with different eigenvalues ceases to be an eigenvector (which eigenvalue?).

I might suggest replacing "Hilbert" with "Banach". Banach spaces are complete normed spaces. Hilbert spaces are Banach spaces whose norms obey the parallelogram law (i.e. there is an inner product on the space from which the norm comes from). It doesn't substantially change the answer, but functional analysis has a lot of nuance. I think it's best to use the right terminology for sake of avoiding misunderstanding.

Sure, I completed my statement: it is Hilbert because the norm is induced by an inner product. Thanks.

I think the confusion arises because you are mixing up two different ideas. When we talk about solutions to the SE we normally mean solutions to the time independent SE i.e. the energy eigenstates given by:
$$ \hat{H}\psi = E\psi $$
However a linear combination of the energy eigenstates is not a solution to the time independent SE because (in general) any combination of the energy eigenstates is time dependent. For why this the case see Is the superposition of stationary states a stationary state? If not, then why not?
The time dependent SE does not have solutions in the sense described above. Instead it tells us about the time evolution of some arbitrary state. Subject to a few basic requirements the wave function at a moment in time could be any function you want, and the time dependent SE then tells us how this state evolves in time.
The aforementioned arbitrary state can be written a linear combination of the energy eigenstates, or indeed as a linear combination of the eigenstates of any operator, which is where completeness comes in.

Thanks. Indeed you exactly mentioned my misconception. But i need a mathematical to deeply get it, if possible. Thanks.

@P.A.M It's not clear to me what maths is needed. I thought what I said above was pretty obvious. Can you give some indication about what you think needs clarifying?

For example, how superposition of eigenvectors of the time independent S.E are not a solution to the S.E. and so on.

@P.A.M That has been discussed before. See for example Is the superposition of stationary states a stationary state? If not, then why not?

It gelped, but not completely cleared mathematically. Thanks
